# Foreach loop not echoing out right text based on column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, union

I have 2 tables on my database. Table `tableA` looks like this:

```
 taid | tanum | tarelation
---------------------------
  30  |  22   |  101
  31  |  88   |  101
```

And table `tableB` looks like this:

```
 tbid | tbnum | tbrelation
---------------------------
  1   |  10   |  101
  2   |  20   |  101
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php
$columns = [];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT tanum FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tbnum FROM tableB;
  ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $columns[] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();
?>

<?php foreach($columns as $column): ?>
    <?php if ($column->tanum): ?>
        <div><?php echo $column->tanum; ?>tanum</div>
    <?php elseif ($column->tbnum): ?>
        <div><?php echo $column->tbnum; ?>tbnum</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So this is the result I want achieved:

```
22tanum
88tanum
10tbnum
20tbnum
```

But this is the result I'm getting instead based on my current code:

```
22tanum
88tanum
10tanum
20tanum
```

As you can see based on the `if statement`, if `$column->tanum` is echoed out, then the word `tanum` should appear after it; and if `$column->tbnum` is echoed out, then the word `tbnum` should appear after it. But instead, only the word `tanum` displays. What is wrong with the code? Please help, thank you

Comment: `UNION ALL` will cause the column to be named `tanum` (because it is the first result in the union statement) so all the rows in the result will be in a column called `tanum`

Comment: @Accountant So how would I fix this? Do I omit the `ALL` and just keep it as `UNION`?

Comment: No, this will not make difference, other than eliminating the duplicate rows, you need to add an extra column that tells if this row from the `tanum` or `tbnum` just like @nick and @metal did in their great answers. Keep up the good well-formatted questions ;)

Comment: @Accountant I understood with their answers, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Accountant pointed out, the column names in a `UNION` are set by the column names from the first select, so you will never see a `$column->tbnum` value. To work around this, you could add a second column to the select which was the column name. For example:

```
$columns = [];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT tanum, 'tanum' AS cname FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tbnum, 'tbnum' FROM tableB;
  ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $columns[] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();
?>

<?php foreach($columns as $column): ?>
    <div><?php echo $column->tanum . $column->cname; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, my job completely dragged my time from here. But yes, you have resolved the issue! And this a perfect workaround, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

you need to reconstruct your code.

```
<?php
$columns = [];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT tanum, 'a' as ident FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tbnum, 'b' as ident FROM tableB;
  ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $columns[$i]['tanum'] = $row['tanum'];
  $columns[$i]['ident'] = $row['ident'];
  $i++;
}
$stmt->close();
?>

<?php foreach($columns as $column): ?>
    <?php if ($column['ident']=='a') ?>
        <div><?php echo $column['tanum']; ?>tanum</div>
    <?php elseif ($column['ident']=='b') ?>
        <div><?php echo $column['tanum']; ?>tbnum</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```